# JS news ticker is not working on home page but working on other pages. How to solve this?

Tags: jquery, javascript

I created this news ticker: http://jsfiddle.net/riffaz/92s92k1d/ and it's working fine in fiddle.

I am trying to add this ticker to the site. For that I put this code on a **PHP widget**

```
<?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $author_id=$post->post_author;
    $args = array('cat'=> 7, 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'paged' => $paged, 'orderby' => date, 'order' => ASC );        
    query_posts( $args);?>  
        <ul class="list-6 ticker" style="height: 82px;">
            <?PHP while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
            <li>
                <h5>
                    <a class="upcomnig" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title();?>">
                        <?php echo get_upcoming_date();?> 
                        <span style="font-size:16px; color: #fe5e08"><?PHP echo get_upcoming_title(); ?></span>
                    </a>
                </h5>
            </li>   
            <?php   endwhile;?> 
        </ul>
```

I put this line into child theme **style.php**

```
.ticker {
    height: 75px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Then on child theme footer.php : I put following code(right above the  tag):

```
function tick(){
        $('.ticker li:first').slideUp( function () { $(this).appendTo($('.ticker')).slideDown(); });
    }
    setInterval(function(){ tick () }, 5000);
```

It does nothing on my home page. It stays where they are on the home page. But if I go to any pages it's working fine. weird. Any ideas how to fix this?

http://www.ldjf.org/ look at the bottom right area.. Footer area  **upcoming events**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the console is firing this error:

> TypeError: $ is not a function

Could be a few things:

WordPress loads jQuery in no-conflict mode so you may need to use jQuery instead of $ when making your selections

```
jQuery('your-selector)
```

Be sure that jQuery has loaded before you set your interval. Based on what I can see you may be trying to access if before it's loaded?

Hope it helps

Comment: Type jQuery into the js console on that site and it returns a good result, it is indeed a fix to one of the original issues

Comment: thanks guys. All $ has been replaced as jQuery and now it's working fine.